# equivalent of surroundContents in angular2

Tags: angular, renderer

i want to use the equivalent of surroundContents() in angular with renderer2

having the caret in a certain position in a contenteditable div i want onClick() to wrap the previous charater in a span 
(I'm assuming that on click the caret position is not changing with preventdefault)

```
onChaining(event) {
      const caretPosition = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      const range = document.createRange();
      range.setStart(caretPosition.commonAncestorContainer, caretPosition.startOffset - 1);
      range.setEnd(caretPosition.commonAncestorContainer, caretPosition.endOffset );

      const wrap= this.renderer.createElement('span');
      range.surroundContents(wrap);

}
```

i want to use renderer2 instead of surroundContents and have that new dom reference so that i can roll back and delete the wrap if needed.

The position of the caret is not known (in a text node) so no previous reference exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems `Renderer2` expects parent objects to have method `appendChild()`. So you cannot use something like `this.renderer.appendChild(range,wrap)` and same with `insertBefore`. But still it is possible to achieve an undoable behavior. According the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents) `surrondContents`:

> This method is nearly equivalent to `newNode.appendChild(range.extractContents());` `range.insertNode(newNode);` So we repeat the mentioned behavior and will keep the range and a clone of a selected text node.

```js
changes: {
  range: Range;content: Node
}[] = [];

render() {
  const caretPosition = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(
    caretPosition.commonAncestorContainer,
    caretPosition.startOffset - 1
  );
  range.setEnd(
    caretPosition.commonAncestorContainer,
    caretPosition.endOffset
  );

  const wrap = this.renderer.createElement("span");
  this.renderer.setStyle(wrap, "background-color", "red");
  const contents = range.extractContents();

  this.changes.push({
    range: range,
    content: contents.cloneNode(true)
  });
  this.renderer.appendChild(wrap, contents);
  range.insertNode(wrap);
}

undo() {
  const action = this.changes.pop();
  const range = action.range;
  const node = range.extractContents();
  range.insertNode(action.content);
}
```

And here is the Stackblitz [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5kjvt-undoable-text-wrapping)